# ASE Export - version 2.73a

Tags: export, add-on

I just installed latest available addon script for ASE Export labeled for Blender version 2.56. But I have Blender version 2.73a and that script seems to do not work at all. I can't even see it in list of addons eighter enabled or disabled and it does not appear in the Import-Export list (which it should)

Looks like it is not compatible. When I try to add the ASE Export zip file (io_export_ase.zip) to the addon script installation, it does nothing :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an issue for the ASE Export Addon developer and not directly a Blender question.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh I already asked the developer (or distributor to be correct), so I do not mind...